# Multiple Azure VM base images with the same name

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

When i use a script to create a VM in Azure and select as the base image "Windows 10, Pro Version 1903" I get the following error: "Found more than 1 image with name 'Windows 10 Pro, Version 1903'. Please pick one from ['Windows 10 Pro, Version 1903', 'Windows 10 Pro, Version 1903']"

If I create a VM from the portal there are two base images with exactly the same name.

```
az lab vm create --resource-group MyTestRG --lab-name MyTestLab --name 'MyScriptVM' --image "Windows 10 Pro, Version 1903" --image-type gallery --size 'Standard_B2s' --admin-username '****' --admin-password '****'
```

How are you supposed to use that base image if you can't tell it exactly which one to use?

Comment: What's your actual question? Right now you're just stating things...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you filter the image via CLI command: `az lab gallery-image list --lab-name mytestlab --resource-group myrg --query "[?name == 'Windows 10 Pro, Version 1903']"`, you will find the similar image reference except for the SKU.
[image]

However, there is no SKU parameter for Azure CLI [az lab vm create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/lab/vm?view=azure-cli-latest#az-lab-vm-create). As a workaround, you could create a VM with DevTest Labs using Azure PowerShell.

[**The sample PowerShell script**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/lab-services/devtest-lab-vm-powershell#powershell-script):

```
[CmdletBinding()]

Param(
[Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]  $SubscriptionId,
[Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]   $LabResourceGroup,
[Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]   $LabName,
[Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]   $NewVmName,
[Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]   $UserName,
[Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]   $Password
)

pushd $PSScriptRoot

try {
    if ($SubscriptionId -eq $null) {
        $SubscriptionId = (Get-AzContext).Subscription.SubscriptionId
    }

    $API_VERSION = '2016-05-15'
    $lab = Get-AzResource -ResourceId "/subscriptions/$SubscriptionId/resourceGroups/$LabResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.DevTestLab/labs/$LabName"

    if ($lab -eq $null) {
       throw "Unable to find lab $LabName resource group $LabResourceGroup in subscription $SubscriptionId."
    }

    #For this example, we are getting the first allowed subnet in the first virtual network
    #  for the lab.
    #If a specific virtual network is needed use | to find it. 
    #ie $virtualNetwork = @(Get-AzResource -ResourceType  'Microsoft.DevTestLab/labs/virtualnetworks' -ResourceName $LabName -ResourceGroupName $lab.ResourceGroupName -ApiVersion $API_VERSION) | Where-Object Name -EQ "SpecificVNetName"

    $virtualNetwork = @(Get-AzResource -ResourceType  'Microsoft.DevTestLab/labs/virtualnetworks' -ResourceName $LabName -ResourceGroupName $lab.ResourceGroupName -ApiVersion $API_VERSION)[0]

    $labSubnetName = $virtualNetwork.properties.allowedSubnets[0].labSubnetName

    #Prepare all the properties needed for the createEnvironment
    # call used to create the new VM.
    # The properties will be slightly different depending on the base of the vm
    # (a marketplace image, custom image or formula).
    # The setup of the virtual network to be used may also affect the properties.
    # This sample includes the properties to add an additional disk under dataDiskParameters

    $parameters = @{
       "name"      = $NewVmName;
       "location"  = $lab.Location;
       "properties" = @{
          "labVirtualNetworkId"     = $virtualNetwork.ResourceId;
          "labSubnetName"           = $labSubnetName;
          "notes"                   = "Windows Server 2016 Datacenter";
          "osType"                  = "windows"
          "expirationDate"          = "2019-12-01"
          "galleryImageReference"   = @{
             "offer"     = "WindowsServer";
             "publisher" = "MicrosoftWindowsServer";
             "sku"       = "2016-Datacenter";
             "osType"    = "Windows";
             "version"   = "latest"
          };
          "size"                    = "Standard_DS2_v2";
          "userName"                = $UserName;
          "password"                = $Password;
          "disallowPublicIpAddress" = $true;
          "dataDiskParameters" = @(@{
            "attachNewDataDiskOptions" = @{
                "diskName" = "adddatadisk"
                "diskSizeGiB" = "1023"
                "diskType" = "Standard"
                }
          "hostCaching" = "ReadWrite"
          })
       }
    }

    #The following line is the same as invoking
    # https://azure.github.io/projects/apis/#!/Labs/Labs_CreateEnvironment rest api

    Invoke-AzResourceAction -ResourceId $lab.ResourceId -Action 'createEnvironment' -Parameters $parameters -ApiVersion $API_VERSION -Force -Verbose
}
finally {
   popd
}
```

The following command provides an example of running the script saved in a file name: Create-LabVirtualMachine.ps1.

```
PS> .\Create-LabVirtualMachine.ps1 -ResourceGroupName 'MyLabResourceGroup' -LabName 'MyLab' -userName 'AdminUser' -password 'Password1!' -VMName 'MyLabVM'
```